# EF 5 Code First: one-to-one and one-to-many associations between two entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two entities: Person and Company. A company has one or many contacts (persons). A company has at least one primary contact (person). What is the best way to implement this?

[image]

Here are the entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Contacts { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryContactId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PrimaryContactId")]
    public virtual Person PrimaryConctact { get; set; }
}
```

The context and the initialiser:

```
public class TolleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public TolleContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new TolleContextInitializer());
    }
}
public class TolleContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TolleContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(TolleContext context)
    {
        var p1 = context.Persons.Add(new Person { PersonName = "Anatoly" });
        var p2 = context.Persons.Add(new Person { PersonName = "Johannes" });
        var contacts = new List<Person> {p1, p2};
        var company = new Company
            {
                CompanyName = "Bool", 
                PrimaryConctact = p1, 
                Contacts = contacts
            };
        context.Companies.Add(company);
        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

If I associate a person as a `PrimaryContact` for a company, it doesn't appear in company.Contacts. When I associate a person as a primary contact and add to the list of contacts for the same company, it throws an error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

I would appreciate an answer about possible ways of implementing such a scenarios.

Comment: Your class diagram is a bit misleading, you have `Company.Contacts`, but your relationship line there indicates that it's a 1-to-1 relationship.  A company can have only one contact, and one primary contact?

Comment: Why do you have PrimaryContact separated out instead of a field on Person?

Comment: Thank you @CodingGorilla, and IronMan84 I have updated the class diagram. I'll try to have PrimaryContact association as a field on Person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a `Person` cannot belong to more than one company. So you can make `Primary` an attribute of `Person`. It reduces model complexity: you only need the one-to-many association. However, it increases business logic complexity: (1) You need to get the primary contact by

```
company.Persons.Where(p => p.IsPrimary).First();
```

which is not as easy as reading a navigation property, and (2) you need logic to ensure that only one `Person` is primary.

If you want to keep the current model, you should save the company and its contacts first and then assign the primary contact in a second transaction. When you do it in one transaction EF can's set the two generated foreign keys at the same time. It must create company first for the FK in Person, and Person first for the FK in Company.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good. I am designing my models right now so I am not forced to keep my models. If I follow your advice and create an attribute IsPrimary, What should be the best way to ensure that a company has only ONE primary contact at a time? I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Just "brute force": make one primary and check if the others aren't.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It must be the best way to implement this in EF code first.